Electron and Vuerouter: "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
The Problem
I want to add Electron to my existing Vue Project. I ran in a problem which I can't find a solution for.
If I run the following configuration with npm run dev (test in browser and auto reload) it works fine. But if I build it (npm run build) and start Electron (npm run electron:start) the page is blank and the console shows me this error:

A solution with new problems
A possible solution will be adding base: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/') to the vite.config.js file. But now, on npm run dev the URL changes to http://localhost:5173/home/username/Desktop/projectname/dist instead of http://localhost:5173. So, the VueRouter starts loading nothing. The user have to click on a link to show content. This happens also on npm run electron:start (after building).
The question
How can I config my project, that I can access the pages directly at the URLs http://localhost:5173/ (HomeView.vue) and http://localhost:5173/about (AboutView.vue) in npm run dev and get a running Electron app with npm run electron:serve?
EDIT: Difference to other questions
There was a suggestion from the community from another question: (Electron renders blank page once I implemented vue-router). If I replace createWebHistory() with createWebHashHistory(), the problem seems solved at first. But the long URL-path is still there. Is there no solution for a "classic" short path (see "The question")?
Folder structure
index.html
index.js
preload.js
vite.config.js
package.json
src/
|- router/
|  |-- router.js
|- views/
|  |- Main.vue
|  |- About.vue
|- App.vue
|- main.js

Source code
index.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("dist/index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

preload.js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
  };

  for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
  }
});

vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const path = require("path");

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  // Adding base results in long path
  // Removing base results in blank Electron app page
  base: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})

package.json
{
  "name": "vue-router-electron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "electron:start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^30.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "vite": "^5.2.8"
  }
}

src/App.vue
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
      <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>

src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')

src/router/router.js
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    }
  ]
})

export default router


Does this answer your question? Electron renders blank page once I implemented vue-router

Partly. It works now, but the URL-path is long as before. Do you know a solution to short them to something like localhost:5173/about on the browser?
